# How to adjust width of image on assigned width?

Tags: html, css

My image doesn't fit with the width. The image is there but does not display properly? This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/iamglenbacs/4uk530L2/). My problem is on the 4th child.

This is my code:

```
nav li:nth-child(4){
    background: url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_76783e20.png') no-repeat -38px -664px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    opacity: .55;
}
```

I tried `background-size: cover`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the width/height from `12px` to `16px` and background position/size to `-33px -578px / 80px auto`

By changing the original width from `92px` to `80px` it resize the image, and using `auto` for its height keep the aspect ratio.

After that is done, a new position is needed to make it show up properly within the div's width/height, hence the `-33px -578px`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4uk530L2/2/)

```
nav li:nth-child(4){
    background: url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_76783e20.png') no-repeat -33px -578px / 80px auto;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    opacity: .55;
}
```

Comment: Yes this works, but I need to adjust the image itself smaller

Comment: @glendonphilippbaculio Updated

Answer (score 0):

Try set the `background-size` and `background-repeat`:

```
nav li:nth-child(4){
    background: url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_76783e20.png');
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    opacity: .55;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a different width & height:

```
nav li:nth-child(4){
    background: url('https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/images/v1_76783e20.png') no-repeat -38px -664px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 22px;
    text-indent: 100%;
    opacity: .55;
}
```

Comment: I need to adjust the image itself smaller like the google homepage